# How to add a custom-made "good-name" like "ax" to pylintrc settings in visual studio code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, settings, pylint, pylintrc

In order to avoid dealing with warnings raised as a result of using the variable `ax` in plotting routines, I would like to add this to the list of `good-name` variables in my python. In Linux, which is the best platform by the way, this is easy to do. However, I am trying to keep and maintain my codes in visual studio code which is installed on a Windows 10. Does any one know how to do this task in the "settings" of the visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

I met such a case using PyCharm, which is the best IDE by the way, And the thing was only in avoiding space-separated good-names.

Works fine:

```
--check-quote-consistency
y
--logging-format-style
new
--max-line-length
120
--good-names
('i','j','k','x','y','s','c','el','a','b','t','l','of','df','pd','Entity')
--bad-names
('foo','bar','kek','KEK')
--disable
C0116
--disable
C0115
--disable
C0114
```

Fails:

```
--check-quote-consistency
y
--logging-format-style
new
--max-line-length
120
--good-names
('i', 'j', 'k', 'x', 'y', 's', 'c', 'el', 'a', 'b', 't', 'l', 'of', 'df', 'pd', 'Entity')
--bad-names
"('foo', 'bar', 'kek', 'KEK')"
--disable
C0116
--disable
C0115
--disable
C0114
```